# How to install the websploit framework in OS X 10.11.2?

Tags: mac, terminal

I wanted to ask how to install websploit in the Mac's terminal. I have downloaded the file from [WebSploit Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websploit/files/WebSploit%20Framework%20V.3.0.0/).

Comment: What file? Is it the source code, or a pkg? What is the file?

Comment: What is your problem? Are you fluent with the command line interface?

Comment: i have the source code

Comment: I would recommend you to install virtualbox and kali linux, instead of running websploit directly from mac

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the name of the file you downloaded was or its URL, *(Are we just supposed to guess?)*.  Assuming it was the *WebSploit-Framework-3.0.0.tar.gz* file from [WebSploit Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/websploit/), *under normal circumstances** you'd simply unpack the file by double-clicking it and it should create a folder named *websploit* containing two files, *install.sh* and *wsf-300.tar.gz.* To install it you'd run the *install.sh* in a Terminal.  Note: install.sh requires being root to run the *script*, so you'd run:

```
cd ~/Downloads/websploit #assuming you extracted the tar.gz to your Download folder
sudo ./install.sh
```

- **For versions previous to OS X 10.11 it should be a straight install as described above.*

For OS X 10.11 herein lies the issue, under normal circumstances the *install.sh script* copies the *wsf-300.tar.gz* file to /usr/share and then finishes the install. However, under OS X 10.11.x with the exception of /usr/local the rest of /usr is protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP) which restricts the *root* account and limits the actions that the *root* user can perform on protected parts of filesystem under OS X. So in this use case it will probably not install unless you temporarily disable SIP, install the *package* and reenable SIP.  That said though, once it's installed it may not function properly once SIP is reenabled.  I say that as I don't have OS X 10.11 to test with and see if anything needs to be written to the */usr/share/websploit/* hierarchical directory structure after the install and during its use it might not be allowed.

Other then temporarily disable SIP to install it, the only suggestion I have is to edit the *install.sh script* changing /usr/share to /usr/local/share and this way you shouldn't have to temporarily disable SIP.

Also where it says `echo "Run From Terminal : sudo websploit"` in the script, this is a message that's echoed and since /usr/local/share/websploit is not in the $PATH that command is not going to work as written.  You will need to resolve this issue as well and it can be done by adding */usr/local/share/websploit/* to the $PATH, otherwise you'd have to type `sudo /usr/local/share/websploit/websploit` to actually run `websploit`.

Comment: no sorry but the problem is that after i write "sudo ./install.sh" i run sudo websploit some problems appear

Comment: an example is:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 471, in <module>
    import dnet
ImportError: No module named dnet

Comment: @Filtar, Based on the two comments you just made to my answer, which you give absolutely no indication of in your question, it's understandable why your question was placed "on hold". In your question you specifically said "I wanted to ask how to install websploit in the Mac's terminal." and not about issues after the install when running it as expressed in these comments you've just made. I'd suggest you ask a new question and be through and detailed to the point there is no misunderstand about what you're asking!